# Allow only positive values in html input element (including decimal values)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation, event-listener

I'm trying to create an input element that only allows positive numbers, including decimal values. It can't have leading zeros, it can't allow users to copy/paste an invalid value (eg. -14.5) in the field.

What I have so far:

```
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>

private handleChange= (e) => {
        let amount = parseFloat(e.target.value);

        if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) {
            amount = 0;
        }

        this.setState({value: amount});
}
```

This works except it always keeps a leading zero. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The following will check the presence of zero at first position.

`e.target.value.indexOf('0') === 0`

> Note: `keyup` event is preferred over `onclick` event for inputs.

---

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />   
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let amount = parseFloat(e.target.value);

        if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0 || e.target.value[0] === '0') {
            amount = '';
        }

        this.setState({value: amount});
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I updated my question with more info. The value attribute is now being read from state. Also I tried it with onKeyUp but it doesn't seem to update the field.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow you to remove leading zero. The zero is always there.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty it is because you're making the value `0` whenever the input is incorrect by this line: *if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) **amount = 0;***

Comment: In the original post I did say this isnt what I want. Whats the solution?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty then set `amount = '';`, which will clear the input

Answer (score 0):

Just don't perform the set state if its `NaN` or `negative`.
Then, when you **intend** to insert anything wrong, it just won't change anything.